# How to use or access newly created pipeline variable inside a exe of C# so that i can assign value inside program in azure dev-ops build pipeline?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How to use or access newly created custom pipeline variable inside a executable created through C# so that I can assign value inside program in Azure DevOps build pipeline?

Let me explain my query in detail:

I have a build pipeline created in Azure DevOps for my project. If I select **EDIT** option on this Pipeline I see a tab or section at top with title as Variables, here selected Pipeline Variables and Clicked on ADD to create my own custom variable lets say `VersionNumber` and checked the settable at queue time option.

On the side I also have a C# based Console Application which accepts command line arguments and does some process.

I created an additional task in the build pipeline of Command Line where i have given my Executable file path such that it can pick and execute it.

**Now, here's is my query or issue:**

1. How to pass the custom variable created above as a command line argument to my exe such that i can assign the value inside my program to be used in further tasks in the pipeline?

If this is not possible then:

2. How can i return values from my exe such that when executed as part of pipeline the values can be used in next tasks of the build pipeline?

**Please note that the logic in the exe is written using C# and inside main method itself as there are only few lines of code which gets executed and gets the value.**

How to achieve or tackle the above issue/query?

Can you please help me on this? and please try to explain in a detailed step by step guide manner as I am bit new to coding, C# and Azure DevOps?

Tried to pass the command line arguments as `$VersionNumber` but was not useful apart from this did not get anything to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Command Line task you pass the variable in this way (under the `Arguments` field):

```
$(VersionNumber)
```

In your C# you read the variable in this way (under your `Main(string[] args)` method):

```
var versionNumber = args[0]
```

To set a new variable that will be available in the next steps you do it in this way:

```
Console.WriteLine("##vso[task.setvariable variable=newVar;]myValue")
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, Can you please let me know, how to pass the command line values accepted in the C# program to be passed in to next task in the Azure Pipeline?

Comment: Do you want to set a variable in C# that will be available in the next tasks?

Comment: Abramczky: Yes, i want the value to be assigned to a variable in C# after processing the data, which can be used in subsequent next tasks in the Pipeline i.e. I take the variable name(ex: versionnumber) in the C# program and assign a value to it such that in next step this variable can be used as it has a value inside it.

Comment: Thanks Shayki (apologies if i am calling you by last name) this really helped, thanks for your time and inputs. Thanks to you I am able to proceed.

Comment: @ChaitanyaNG You're welcome! I glad to help. and my first name is Shayki :)